# microstrategy join uncommon attribute

Tags: join, attributes, report, cross-join, microstrategy

I'd like to make a report that relate:

- 2 metric from two distinct fact table
- 1 attribute (from a Lookup table) common to both fact table
- 1 attribute (from another Lookup table) that is present in only one fact table

In my environment, Microstrategy does a cross join and I have this result 
[esempio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx0wU.png)

I want that Microstrategy avoid cross join to retrieve the value of the first metric. Is there any solution?

Thanks a lot to all

Comment: how did you defile the levels for the metrics? can you post the sql generated? which is the attribute in both, which one in only one? you shouldn't get a cross join, but an error that the metric doesn't exist for the report level (attribute 1 and attribute2)

Comment: I don't want to add manually the level for the metrics. In my example the level for both the metric is "report level". The common attribute is "consulente" and the uncommon attribute is "Valuta" 
which is related only with the metric "Fatturato". I know that If I add in the metric "budget" the level "valuta" and set as filter "ignore" I'll have the right behavior, but how I said before I don't want to add it manually.

Comment: any reason why you don't want to add the level to the metric?

Comment: in an enterprise environment it's so risky because in every metric from the fact tables you must add all the attributes that you want ignore. In our case we have a lot of attributes and a lot of metrics/facts that don't have connections and we want to allow the users to do free analisys, without the risk of having cross join.

Comment: every MicroStrategy developer will tell you that level metrics are used in enterprise environment. As you can see there are different level of aggregation for different fact tables and level metrics are the way to cope with that. You need to be sure to have the right definition of the facts to create the right level for the metrics. I agree that it can be annoying sometimes but it's the way to do it with MicroStrategy

Comment: thanks for the advise, but that doesn't help me :(

Comment: the solution is to use a level metric, this is the way to use MicroStrategy. Otherwise you can use a free form sql report, but it's like to use a hammer to write on a computer keyboard

Answer (score 0):

A cross join is the only way you can display a metric and an unrelated fact together on the same report.  Same would be true if you were thinking about joining tables that don't have any keys in common, independently of MSTR.

If you would prefer for the user to see an error if they combine metrics and attributes in a way that would result in a cross join, you can use the VLDB setting for "Cartesian Join Warning":  "Cancel Execution only when a warehouse table is involved in either side of the cartesian join."  With this setting if the user tried to put "Valuta" together with "Budget" they would see an error message instead of a cross join.